# React-Redux Reducer - First element added to an array is undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a redux reducer, and for some reason the first value that I add to an array in the state, gets set to undefined. This is when the case is "USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE". Here's the code for the reducer;

```
import { CLEAR_DATA, USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE, USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants";

const initialState = {
    users: [],
    usersLoaded: 0
};

export const users = function (state = initialState, action)
{
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case USERS_DATA_STATE_CHANGE: 
            console.log(action.user);
            return {...state, users: [...state.users, action.user]}

        case USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {...state, usersLoaded: state.usersLoaded + 1, users: state.users.map(function (user) {user.uid === action.uid ? {...user, posts: action.posts} : user})}

        case CLEAR_DATA:
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here's what the data is for each user when logged right before changing the state;

[image]

And here is what the array looks like after these 3 additions;

[image]

Cannot work out at all why this is happening so any help would be appreciated,
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually happens in your `USERS_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE`.  The callback function in the `state.users.map` doesn't return anything, so it replaces all users in the array with `undefined`.

An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is an implied return, so you can do this:

```
users: state.users.map(user =>
  user.uid === action.uid ? { ...user, posts: action.posts } : user
)
```

With `function(user){}`, you need the `return` keyword:

```
users: state.users.map(function (user) {
  return user.uid === action.uid ? { ...user, posts: action.posts } : user;
})
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly fine now. Completely forgot that an arrow function has an implied return.